# Probabilities for Pure birth Process

Tags: poisson-process, birth-death-process

Consider a pure birth process starting from $X(0) = 0$ with birth parameters $\lambda_0 = 1.4$ and $\lambda_1 = 1.8$ Compute the following probabilities
$\mathbb{P}(X(0.2) = 0)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X(0.2) = 1)$

So far I have calculated $\mathbb{P}(X(0.2) = 0) = \frac{(1.4*0.2)^0*e^{-1.4*0.2}}{0!} = 0.75568 $

But I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate the next one, so far I have tried assuming since we have not reached 1 yet since the time interval is [0,0.2] so we have $(1.4*0.2)^1*e^{-1.4*0.2}$ but it isn't correct and also $(1.8*0.2)^1*e^{-1.8*0.2}$ to no avail. I would appreciate any help with this question

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, you have to consider all possible times at which the birth happened, and it could have happened anywhere in the interval $[0,T]$.

$$
\begin{split}P(X(T)=1)&=\int_0^T dt_1P(X(T)=1|X(t_1)=1)P(X(t_1)=1|X(0)=0)\\&=
\int_0^T dt_1e^{-\lambda_1(T-t_1)}(1-e^{-\lambda_0t_1})\\&=
\frac{1-e^{-\lambda_1T}}{\lambda_1}+\frac{e^{-\lambda_1T}- e^{-\lambda_0T}}{\lambda_1-\lambda_0}
\end{split}$$